# Salesforce REST API Login?

Tags: java, rest, oauth, salesforce, restful-authentication

I am examining a sample which is in the salesforce developer site.

In that sample when we click a link it will be redirected to the salesforce login page. If the  login successful, then an access token is issued.

I dont want my application to redirect to the salesforce login page. In the existing sample the environment variable is set to,

> "https://login.salesforce.com"

What should I do to avoid redirecting to salesforce login page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're describing, sounds like OAuth (just because you mention access-token).

There's a good example of OAuth being used in Salesforce below...

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that i have to use Username-Password oauth flow for my need. https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm => this is the link we have to refer. But although i have followed the steps my app still redirecting. :(

Comment: Are you following the "oauth dance" steps correctly?  Remember you need 3 things, request-token-url, api-url, access-token-url.

Comment: SOLUTION: Hi all, I have arrived the solution to my problem. Actually, I was examining the sample given in the link http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API . Then implemented OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow which is from https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm#send_up_response. It solves my problem. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Just so you know the username password flow is only recommended for testing purposes, if you need a non use interaction for the JWT Bearer token for is recommended

Comment: Another answer lost due to link rot

Answer (score 6):

**SOLUTION:**

Hi all, I have arrived the solution to my problem. Actually, I was examining the sample given in the link http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API . Then implemented OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow which is from https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm#send_up_response. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is sample Java code that uses Username-Password OAuth flow:

```
public class AccountQuery 
{
    // The connection data
    private static final String query = "SELECT Name, Idfrom Account";
    private static final String clientId = "theID";
    private static final String clientSecret = "theSecret";
    // THis is meaningless in our context
    private static final String redirectUri = "https://localhost:8443/_callback";
    private static final String environment = "https://login.salesforce.com";   
    private static String tokenUrl = null;
    private static final String username = "username";
    private static final String password = "passwordPlusSecret";
    private static String accessToken = null;
    private static String instanceUrl = null;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {       
        // Step 0:  Connect to SalesForce.
        System.out.println("Getting a token");
        tokenUrl = environment + "/services/oauth2/token";
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(tokenUrl);     
        post.addParameter("grant_type", "password");
        post.addParameter("client_id", clientId);
        post.addParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
        post.addParameter("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
        post.addParameter("username", username);
        post.addParameter("password", password);

        try {
            httpclient.executeMethod(post);
            try {
                JSONObject authResponse = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new InputStreamReader(post.getResponseBodyAsStream())));
                System.out.println("Auth response: " + authResponse.toString(2));

                accessToken = authResponse.getString("access_token");
                instanceUrl = authResponse.getString("instance_url");

                System.out.println("Got access token: " + accessToken);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
        } catch (HttpException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }       
        System.out.println("We have an access token: " + accessToken + "\n" + "Using instance " + instanceUrl + "\n\n");

        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod get = new GetMethod(instanceUrl + "/services/data/v28.0/query");

        // set the token in the header
        get.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        // set the SOQL as a query param
        NameValuePair[] params = new NameValuePair[1];

        params[0] = new NameValuePair("q",query);
        get.setQueryString(params);     

        try {
            httpclient.executeMethod(get);
            if (get.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                // Now lets use the standard java json classes to work with the results
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject( new JSONTokener( new InputStreamReader(get.getResponseBodyAsStream())));
                System.out.println("Query response: "+ response.toString(2));//.substring(0, 500));                 
                System.out.println(response.getString("totalSize") + " record(s) returned\n\n");
                JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("records");               
                Account[] accounts = new Gson().fromJson(results.toString(), Account[].class);
                return accounts;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Java, the easiest way is to use Spring Social Salesforce: https://github.com/iirekm/spring-social-salesforce

Just follow the Facebook tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/, and shortly-speaking add dependency to Spring Social Salesforce and replace everywhere in code "facebook" with "salesforce".